# Angular js post cannot serialize object

Tags: javascript, c#, json, angularjs, typescript

Currently I am doing an AngularJS Post to my controller and not a form submission. I have an object called sharingInfo that is always set to null in the controller after a post call. I believe there is an issue with the JSON serializer.

In Angular I am posting the data like so

```
$scope["TemplateForm"].$setPristine();
                    var model = getFormData($('#TemplateForm'));

                    model.Publish = publish;
                    model["Template.CommitteeWithAccessCanEditReusable"] = $scope.Model.Template.CommitteeWithAccessCanEditReusable;
                    model["Template.SharingInfo"]  = angular.toJson($scope.Model.Template.SharingInfo);
                    $http({
                        method: "POST",
                        url: "/Template/UpdateTemplateContent",
                        data: model
                    }).then...morecode=>
```

in the debugger the template.sharingInfo is serialized into

```
"{"CommitteesWithAccess":[{"TenantId":32727,"DisplayName":"20190304 Ted Test Committee","IsStatic":false,"RootCommitteeId":null}]""{"CommitteesWithAccess":[{"TenantId":32727,"DisplayName":"20190304 Ted Test Committee","IsStatic":false,"RootCommitteeId":null}]"
```

When the data hits the controller the debugger always has the value set to null. Moreover, for objects of type string or boolean, I am able to set the value. I believe its just not serializing into the object so I decided to serialize the sharingInfo to see what it expects. I did this by adding a dummy sharingInfo variable of type string. This variable keeps the json string and then deserializes it in the controller. This workaround isnt maintainable because it forces me to define two variable of the same name but different types and I cannot change the sharingInfo object.

My controller method is defined below: the templatedto.sharingInfo is a string and the templatedto.template.sharinginfo is the object

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        [RequireReusablesPermissions]
        public ActionResult UpdateTemplateContent(SaveTemplateDto templateDto)
        {

            if (templateDto.SharingInfo != null && templateDto.Template.SharingInfo != null)
            {
                templateDto.Template.SharingInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReusableDto.SharingState>(templateDto.SharingInfo) as ReusableDto.SharingState;
            }
            //just to see what this gives me tbd
            var serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(templateDto.Template.SharingInfo);

            var validationResults = TemplateValidator.GetValidationErrors(templateDto);

            if (validationResults?.Any() == true)
            {
                return new AjaxResult<ReusableDto>
                {
                    ResponseResultCode = ResponseResultCode.Failure,
                    MessagesHeader = $"{Resources.UnableToSaveTemplate} {string.Join(",", validationResults)}"
                };
            }
```

the "serializedObject" returns this string:

```
"{\"CommitteesWithAccess\":[{\"TenantId\":32727,\"DisplayName\":\"20190304 Ted Test Committee\",\"IsStatic\":false,\"RootCommitteeId\":null}]}"
```

As you can see the angular.toJson and the c# JSON serializer, serialize the object differently.
how can I get it to do the expected serializing in Angular?

My Object definition is below for reference. The reuasableDTO is template

```
     public class SaveTemplateDto
        {
            public ReusableDto Template { get; set; }
            public bool IsNewTemplate => Template?.Id == Guid.Empty;

            // Model binding properties 
            public bool Publish { get; set; }
            public string SharingInfo { get; set; }
        }

 public class ReusableDto
    {
        public SharingState SharingInfo { get; set; }

        public class TenantDto
        {
            public short TenantId { get; set; }
            public string DisplayName { get; set; }
            public bool IsStatic { get; set; }
            public string RootCommitteeId { get; set; }
        }

        public class SharingState 
        {
            public List<TenantDto> CommitteesWithAccess { get; set; }
            public List<TenantDto> CommitteesWithoutAccess { get; set; }            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a wrapper object

```
public class CommitteesWithAccessModel
{
    public SaveTemplateDto  SaveTemplateDto  {get; set;}
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
[RequireReusablesPermissions]
public ActionResult UpdateTemplateContent(CommitteesWithAccessModel templateDto)
{
...
}
```